# How can I use jQuery live() after slice()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Why won't `live()` work after `slice()`?
What am I doing wrong here?

```
$('.object').slice(1).live('mouseenter', function() {
    alert();
});
```

...

```
<div class="object">
    1
    <div class="object">
        2
        <div class="object">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why won't `live()` work after `slice()`?

[Straight from the API docs:](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to `.live()`. Rather, the `.live()` method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.

**Use a different selector.** For example:

```
$('div.object:gt(0)').live('mouseenter', function()
{
    // super awesome life things
});
```

Comment: Yes, that will work just fine. As it turns out the suggested selector I have is _too_ specific... removed.

Answer (score 1):

DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.

@ http://api.jquery.com/live/